# How to control the style of a parent element with CSS and VueJS?

Tags: php, css, html, laravel-5, vue.js

I loop through a set of users to build a table using ***VueJS*** 'for' statement.

There's a column called "approved". If it's true then I want the entire table row to be green. How to achieve that?

```
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="user in users" >
                    <td v-for="key in columns">
                        <!-- At This point I can tell if the user is approved but how to change the style of the parent tr element?? -->
                        <span v-if='key == "approved" && user[key] == 0'>
                            Not Approved
                        </span>

                        <span v-else-if='key == "approved" && user[key] == 1'>
                            Approved!
                        </span>

                        <span v-else>
                            {{user[key]}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have "approved" column you can simply achieve it in this way:

```
<tr v-for="user in users" 
    v-bind:style="{backgroundColor: user['approved'] == 1 ? 'green' : '' }">
```

or

```
<tr v-for="user in users" 
    v-bind:class="{green: user['approved'] == 1}">


.green {
     background-color: green:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method to assign class to `tr` dynamically

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="user in users" :class="{'green': isApprove(user, columns)}">
    <td v-for="key in columns">
        <!-- At This point I can tell if the user is approved but how to change the style of the parent tr element?? -->
        <span v-if='key == "approved" && user[key] == 0'>
            Not Approved
        </span>

        <span v-else-if='key == "approved" && user[key] == 1'>
            Approved!
        </span>

        <span v-else>
            {{user[key]}}
        </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>


<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    isApprove(user, columns) {
      for (let idx in columns) {
        const key = columns[idx]
        if (key === 'approved' && user[key] == 1) {
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }
  }

</script>

<style>
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can shorten the syntax using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.